# what's best practice for temporarily storing images until their database entity is created?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, local-storage, temporary-files

I'm working in ASP.NET 4.0, and I've got a large web form which represents a single business entity.  A user can upload multiple images associated with the entity.  The entity is created and assigned a GUID upon submitting the form.  The files will be stored to a file system.

The problem is that we have to name the files after the GUID that is assigned to the entity after it is inserted to the database.  So before the submit button is clicked, we will have several image files floating around in limbo.

There are obvious answers to this question -- you save the images to the file system and then when the business entity is created, you rename those files.  However, I believe that there must be very strong patterns and several key details that would make for a very robust system.  What's best practice for this scenario?

Comment: Is it mandatory to name the files after the entity's ID?

Comment: yes it is.  As there will be several files per entity, they will be named [GUID]-1, [GUID]-2, etc

Comment: That kind of complicates things :(. If you could name them whatever you wanted, you could just put up a table with two columns: EntityId & ImageFileName. I guess you'll have to use renames no matter what. Or assign IDs before inserting to the database.

Answer (score 1):

One of the nice things about GUIDs is that they can be created anywhere.  So have your app create and assign the GUID and then perform the insert on the entity with the pre-assigned GUID.  Your app then has the GUID to use in naming the file.

If this isn't feasible then your renaming scheme seems to me to be about the best bet.

Comment: What if the form is eventually cancelled? There will be files (and possibly - directories) that must be deleted. This is why I would delay storing files to their "permanent place" until the data from the form is really being saved.

Comment: Also, I know that GUIDs are guaranteed unique when generated by the Sql Server.  Are they guaranteed unique when generated disparately on the web server and on the database?

Comment: @HaterTot: Yes, GUIDs are guaranteed unique whether you are doing Guid.New() in .NET or UNIQUEIDENTIFIER() in T-SQL.
@binaryLV: If the form is canceled, you don't insert the entity so don't save the file.  The multi-part form data is simply discarded - no clean up necessary.

Comment: if it was that easy, I think HaterTot would not have to think about naming/storing files temporarily. Or would he? If all files and main data is stored in single HTTP request, there's no problem with inserting data into DB and then storing files with GUID from DB as filename. If there's a problem with naming files because of not having GUID from DB, it makes me think that files are uploaded in one request, textual form data - in another request, when files are already uploaded. In this case, periodical clean up IS necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only writing this as you mentioned 'very robust system':

I would try to prevent maintaining any state other than in your database (that includes the file system), as it creates more maintenance complexity in the long run. You have to clean files up some time anyway, I'd prefer to clean it up from the database.
File system is (in most cases) not ideal as it does not:

- span multiple front-end servers, so less scalable
- operate transactional
  (most of the time)
- when you restore a
  backup of your DB, your files will be
  in 'Limbo' too

Maybe this is not really the answer you're looking for as you might not be able to change your requirements (sorry if it is not), but as you mentioned to make a system 'very robust' I thought this might be relevant.

If you're using SQL 2008, have a look at FILESTREAM:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx

Comment: you've made a nice argument for going full DB.  However using their filesystem is a requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I would stay away from saving the uploads in the file system, and instead move them to the DB. That way you would have one less resource to worry about in your backup and disaster recovery plans, thus less complexity thus less maintenance. The way I used to do it was to save the files on the file server once they are uploaded, then copy them to the DB once the form is submitted and accepted, then delete it from the file system. There would also be a regular maintenance script that cleans up the "limbo" folder of any orphaned files.